# Insert em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, relacionamento

Eai pessoal, to criando um SQL pra insert em tabelas relacionadas, são as seguintes tabelas:

```
tb_Customer(id_Customer INTEGER [PK], nm_Customer VARCHAR, cpf_cnpj NUMERIC)

dm_address_type(cd_address_type CHAR(1) [PK], ds_address_type VARCHAR)

tb_customer_address(id_customer [PFK],  cd_address_type CHAR(1)[PFK], street VARCHAR, lot INTEGEER, references VARCHAR, zip_code VARCHAR)

SELECT * FROM dm_address_type
cd_address_type: R , C , O
ds_address_type: Residencial, Comercial, Outros
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, para cadastrar o cliente 'JOAZINHO' seria o SQL a seguir?:

Joãozinho Silva - 888.777.666-55

Endereço Residencial: Rua das Flores, 1. CEP: 01234-567
Endereço comercial: Rua das Pedras, 100 Conjunto 200. CEP: 01234-567

```
INSERT INTO tb_Customer(nm_customer, cpf_cnpj) VALUES ("Jãozinho Silva", "888.777.666-55")

SET @ic_Customer = LAST_INSERT_ID()

INSERT INTO tb_customer_address(street, lot, references, zip_code, id_customer, cd_address_type) values ('Rua das Flores', '1', 'references', 01234-567', @id_Customer, 'R')

INSERT INTO tb_customer_address(street, lot, references, zip_code, id_customer, cd_address_type) values ('Rua das Pedras', '100 Conjunt 200', 'references', 01234-567', @id_Customer, 'C')
```

E outra duvida é de quantos endereços diferentes posso cadastrar para cada clientes? Quantos necessário, né?

Vlww pessoal. Abraço!

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MySQL ou SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL, mas difere  muito o uso do insert? VLW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua escolha de TAG ficou difícil saber se você está usando SQL Server ou MySQL.

Portanto:

- Se for SQL Server:
  Você não consegue utilizar LAST_INSERT_ID, precisa pegar o dado de outra forma. Você pode fazer isso utilizando: SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @@IDENTITY ou IDENT_CURRENT. Você pode ler mais sobre estas 3 opções [neste link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/).
- Se for MySQL Server:
  Criei um banco aqui conforme o que você disse que colocou no seu. Ainda assim algumas coisas vão depender de como você criou seu banco, mas:

1 - Quando você tenta executar esse INSERT você receberá um erro de dado truncado por causa do CPF conter pontos. Não sei te dizer se existem maneiras de formatar o CPF para inserir na tabela, mas você consegue fazer isso depois, na consulta e no programa que for utilizar os dados, então não há necessidade de gravar os dados com os pontos como você fez;

2 - Você definiu a variável como @ic_Customer, mas nas linhas debaixo você define @id_Customer;

3 - A palavra 'references' é uma palavra reservada do MySQL. Não é recomendado utilizar palavras reservadas na sua base;

4 - No segundo endereço, em '100 Conjunt 200' você terá problemas com dado truncado. Você definiu que este campo seria uma INTEGER. Pegando esse texto de exemplo você possui um campode tamanho 15B. Integers suportam até 8B (quando você usa a opção BigInt. Eu separaria o número da casa e o complemento em dois campos diferentes (um para número com valor numérico e outro para complemento com varchar);

5 - Existem alguns erros de símbolos aí, o correto seria que seu código fosse o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO tb_Customer(nm_customer, cpf_cnpj) VALUES ("Jãozinho Silva", "88877766655");

SET @id_Customer = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO tb_customer_address(street, lot, reference, zip_code, id_customer, cd_address_type) values ('Rua das Flores', '1', 'references', '01234-567', @id_Customer, 'R');

INSERT INTO tb_customer_address(street, lot, reference, zip_code, id_customer, cd_address_type) values ('Rua das Pedras', '100 Conjunt 200', 'references', 01234-567', @id_Customer, 'C')
```

6 - Sim, você consegue cadastrar vários endereços para o mesmo cliente.